# Why do I get the following error installing gittfs?

Tags: git-tfs, chocolatey

I am using the following command via choclaty to install gittfs.

`cinst gittfs`

Seems to go okay until I get the following error:

```
Write-Error : gittfs did not finish successfully. Boo to the chocolatey gods!
-----------------------
[ERROR] Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
-----------------------
```

Boo indeed, what path parameter are they talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue in chocolatey v0.9.8.23 that occurs when you install it and don't close and reopen the shell. See https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/issues/371 for more information.

As a workaround, you just need to close and reopen the shell.